# How to convert Web service output(XMLNode) to Dataset in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, vb.net-2010

I have written code as below

> ```
>             Dim xNode As XmlNode
>             xNode = proclaimService.ProClaim_Get_Exclusions(sSQL)
>             XmlData = New StringReader(xNode.OuterXml)
>             Dim xmlString As String
>             xmlString = xNode.OuterXml
> ```

Here in xmlString I am getting below

```
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
  <Table>
  <company /> 
  <Policy>10163067</Policy> 
  <Rec_ty>Ex</Rec_ty> 
  <Seq_no xml:space="preserve"></Seq_no> 
  <Dt_last_updt>Dec 3 2003</Dt_last_updt> 
  <Coverage_no>All</Coverage_no> 
  <Client_no>65083406</Client_no> 
  <Document_name>Exclusion</Document_name> 
  <Print_ind /> 
  <Retention_ind /> 
  <Exclusion_type>Exclu</Exclusion_type> 
  <Comment01>blessure,maladie ou trouble d'un ou des deux genoux, y compr</Comment01> 
  <comment02>is les complications, traitements ou chirurgies connexes.</comment02> 
  <comment03 xml:space="preserve"></comment03> 
  <comment04 xml:space="preserve"></comment04> 
  <comment05 xml:space="preserve"></comment05> 
  <comment06 xml:space="preserve"></comment06> 
  <comment07 xml:space="preserve"></comment07> 
  <comment08 xml:space="preserve"></comment08> 
  <comment09 xml:space="preserve"></comment09> 
  <comment10 xml:space="preserve"></comment10> 
  </Table>
  </NewDataSet>
```

I am using Below code to create dataset

> ```
>             XmlData = New StringReader(xmlString)
>             reader = New XmlTextReader(XmlData)
>             xmlDs.ReadXml(reader)
>             Dset = xmlDs
> ```

But in XmlData I am not getting anything.....
How to convert it to Dataset using VB.NET???

Comment: Are you reading from a file?

Comment: @dbasnett no...I am getting xml string from webservice which is returning XmlNode

Comment: updated my answer.  Pay attention to the number of tables returned.  The site I tested returned 14...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some more info it is hard to know how to answer.  Here is an example that works with a file.  Note the comments.

```
    Dim xmlStrm As New IO.StreamReader(pathToFile)
    'xmlStrm could be a .GetResponseStream from a web response
    'Dim xmlStrm As IO.Stream = someWebResp.GetResponseStream

    Dim Dset As New DataSet
    Using reader As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlStrm)
        Dset.ReadXml(reader)
    End Using
    xmlStrm.Close()
    xmlStrm.Dispose()

    Debug.WriteLine(Dset.Tables.Count)

    For Each rw As DataRow In Dset.Tables(0).Rows
        'as example show first two columns
        Debug.WriteLine(rw(0).ToString & " " & rw(1).ToString)
    Next
```

edit: From a web site returning XML

```
    Dim someReq As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(someURL)

    Dim someResp As Net.WebResponse = someReq.GetResponse()
    Dim someStrm As IO.Stream = someResp.GetResponseStream()

    Dim someDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    someDoc.Load(someStrm)

    Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Parse(someDoc.InnerXml)

    Dim Dset As New DataSet
    Using reader As Xml.XmlReader = xe.CreateReader
        Dset.ReadXml(reader)
    End Using

    Debug.WriteLine(Dset.Tables.Count)
```